# Why am I getting ClusterNotFoundException The referenced cluster was inactive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

Trying to use ecs-cli and getting referenced cluster was inactive?

I don't see where I specify a cluster?

```
aws ecs create-cluster --region us-west-2 --cluster burrfg

{
    "cluster": {
        "status": "ACTIVE", 
        "clusterName": "burrfg", 
        "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 0, 
        "pendingTasksCount": 0, 
        "runningTasksCount": 0, 
        "activeServicesCount": 0, 
        "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:5533219:cluster/burrfg"
    }
}


ecs-cli compose --file docker-compose.yml service up
WARN[0000] Skipping unsupported YAML option for service...  option name=expose service name=burrfg
INFO[0001] Using ECS task definition                     TaskDefinition="ubuntudock:3"
ERRO[0001] Error creating service                        error="ClusterNotFoundException: The referenced cluster was inactive.\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 28eab6b7-7eb2-11e9-be1a-633df2a55bcb" service=ubuntudock
INFO[0001] Created an ECS service                        service=ubuntudock taskDefinition="ubuntudock:3"
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  burrfg:
    image: burrfg
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
      - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080/udp"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=8080
    command:
      sh -c 'npm i && node app.js'
      echo 'ready'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren’t specifying the cluster to create the service on, try using `ecs-cli configure` to set the default cluster for ex’s-cli or pass the cluster config using `ecs-cli compose --cluster-config burrfg file docker-compose.yml —service up`

Also, why create the cluster with AWS cli and not `ecs-cli up`?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-configure.html